# Retornar resultado da query com node

Tags: mysql, node.js

Quando faço um select no meu banco *MYSQL*, obtenho a resposta e consigo exibir isso para o usuário, Mas o problema é que isso não e o suficiente,apenas pegar o resultado e exibi-lo, preciso por exemplo verificar se determinado id tem dados em uma tabela,e se caso não tenha, efetuar o *INSERT*.

Este e meu código no server side.

```
app.post('/companies', function(req, res) {

    console.log('enviado do app'+req.body.id);

    let filter = '';
    filter = ' WHERE id_companies=' + req.body.id;
    execSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM companies' + filter, res); 
    "é aqui que eu preciso usar a variável results que eu recebo lá embaixo para continuar"
});

//inicia o servidor
app.listen(port);
console.log('API funcionando!');

function execSQLQuery(sqlQry, res){
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '***************',
    port     : 1111,
    user     : '**************',
    password : '************',
    database : '****************'

  connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, results, fields){
      if(error) 
        res.json(error);
      else
        res.json(results);


      connection.end();

      console.log('executou!');

  });

}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço demais.

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não passa uma [função de callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Callback_function) para a `execSQLQuery` executar com o resultado ao invés de passar o objeto `res`?

Ficaria algo assim:

```
app.post('/companies', function(req, res) {
  // ...

  execSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM companies' + filter, function(
    error,
    results,
    fields
  ) {
    // Faça qualquer operação que quiser aqui...

    res.json(error || results)
  })
})

// ...

function execSQLQuery(sqlQry, callback) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({/* ... */})

  connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, results, fields) {
    connection.end()

    callback(error, results, fields)
  })
}
```

Dessa forma você pode executar qualquer operação dentro da função de callback e chamar `res.json` quando terminar.