# Como acessar o retorno de uma query

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando adicionar valores utilizando `push`, acontece que não está funcionando...

Só funciona dentro do bloco de código `connection.query()`.

Existe alguma maneira de acessar variáveis e adicionar valores a ela fora desse escopo?

Meu código atual:

```
let customers = []

connection.query("SELECT * FROM customers", async (error, data) => {
  customers.push(data) // console.log(customers) aqui funciona
})

console.log(customers) // retorno => [] (vazio)
```

Comment: Ja tentou usar o `await` no `conection.query`? provavelmente o console.log está sendo executado antes do `customers.push(data)`

Comment: Além do link já indicado acima, ver tb: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264291/112052

Comment: Sim, já tentei inclusive eu iria colocar o código aqui, mas como foi o mesmo retorno `[]`eu não coloquei